# php openssl_csr_new(): Error signing request debug

Tags: php, debugging, openssl, csr

I have a project that creates certificates for users. And magically today it's failing.

The only error message I get is: `Warning: openssl_csr_new(): Error signing request`

I debugged the code but I don't understand what is failing...

This is the code:

```
    $configArgs = array(
        'config' => $this->configFile,
        'encrypt_key' => false,
        'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
    );
    return openssl_csr_new($dn, $privKey, $configArgs);
```

The config file last update is from 2018-08-02 so I don't think this is the problem?

I dumped the variables but I don't see what is wrong.

```
array:7 [▼
  "commonName" => "TEST"
  "emailAddress" => "TEST@TEST.COM"
  "organizationName" => "TEST/0001"
  "organizationalUnitName" => "TEST/999090"
  "localityName" => "TEST"
  "stateOrProvinceName" => "TEST"
  "countryName" => "ES"
]
OpenSSL key resource @7
array:3 [▼
  "config" => "/var/www/html/src/Actions/openssl.cnf"
  "encrypt_key" => false
  "req_extensions" => "v3_req"
]
```

What can I do now? Why is throwing this error? What can cause this exception without touching the code?

An update of something?

php is still same version, 7.2.

UPDATED: I could debug a little with `openssl_error_string()` method.

I inserted this code before and after calling the `openssl_csr_new()` method:

```
while (($e = openssl_error_string()) !== false) {
    echo "<pre>";print_r($e);echo "</pre>";
}
```

And this is the output:

```
"BEFORE calling openssl_csr_new()"
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:2406F076:random number generator:RAND_load_file:reseed error
error:04081003:rsa routines:rsa_builtin_keygen:BN lib
"AFTER calling openssl_csr_new"
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0D0DC041:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_sign_ctx:malloc failure
```

Comment: Has something changed in `/var/www/html/src/Actions/openssl.cnf`? Have you looped over all elements of `openssl_error_string()`?

Comment: The last change is from 2018-08-02. It worked fine these 2 years so... The method: `openssl_error_string()` returns this: `error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value`

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076800/openssl-pkey-new-throws-error-configuration-file-routinesnconf-get-stringno-va)?

Comment: Yes, I figured out the first errors are only warnings, I can remove adding lines on the config file, but the last one persists. Something about memory? I did a `df` and there is nothing completed.